# What do we call a material property that has non-equal values when evaluated in opposite directions?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, material-science, continuum-mechanics

What do we call a material property that has non-equal values when evaluated in opposite directions?

That is, if the material property $k_{ij}$ has a value of $X$ along the direction defined by the unit vector $u_i = (1, 0, 0)$ and a value of $Y$ along the direction $u_i = (-1, 0, 0)$, where $X \ne Y$, what do we call this property?

I don't think we can call it *anisotropic-asymmetric* because no matter what *asymmetric* matrix (or *symmetric* matrix) is defined for $k_{ij}$, the scalar value in opposite directions will be the same. The scalar value of the material property in a direction defined by the unit vector $u_i$ is:
$$k=k_{ij}u_i u_j$$

A physical example could be to consider a fluid flowing through a porous material that adheres to the equation $$q=k_{ij} \Delta p/L$$
where $q$ is the flow rate, $\Delta p$ is the change in pressure over the length $L$ of the flow in the direction of $u_i$.

Consider when 50% (say) of the fluid passages in the porous medium have one-way check valves, all oriented in the same direction (along the $u_i=(1,0,0)$ direction, say). When flow is moving in the $u_i=(1,0,0)$ direction all the check valves are open and the scalar value of $k_{ij}$ is equal to $X$:
$$k=k_{ij}u_i u_j=X$$
However, when flow is moving in the opposite direction, $u_i=(-1,0,0)$, all the check valves are closed, closing off 50% of the fluid passages, and the scalar value of $k_{ij}$ is equal to $Y=0.5X$:
$$k=k_{ij}u_i u_j=Y=0.5X$$

Comment: I am not sure there is a name. Not enough materials are full of check valves to make this important.

Comment: @mmesser314 (+1) How do you know, you said yourself you are not sure.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a continuum material?

Comment: @Chemomechanics Flow through porous media and the equation describing it is based on the assumption that the porous medium domains of interest may be described as continua. Consider a homogeneous structured porous medium composed of elongated mineral grains which are larger at one end than the other and oriented with their larger ends pointing in one direction. Within each pore cavity enclosed by the grains is a free particle that may pass through pore-throat formed by the larger ends of the grains but not through the pore-throat formed by the smaller ends of the grains.

Comment: (This particular case is sometimes called a fluid diode.)